# Retrieving post data submitted via HTML form

Tags: html, forms, post

Do I have a way to retrieve post data submitted via HTML form? Particularily in Firefox, on Windows XP. I suppose Firefox holds it in it's directory inside Application Data, but they are bunch of files which names do not give any clue. They don't even have extensions, some of them are text, some binary.

Just don't tell me that post data is not stored anywhere locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submitted form data is not stored locally or remotely unless you have software built to do something with it. With some of the new HTML5 additions (local storage) you could code up something in JavaScript to store your posted form data but this would only be on your computer. Generally you want to post data to a remote server for processing and/or storage using one of the many server-side programming languages.

Hope this helps and sorry to give you the answer you didn't want to hear. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I supposed that is the answer, I asked just for the case. In my opinion, browsers should at least give you the choice to save your textarea data by default, unless you tell them otherwise. Because textarea data is usually not something confidential.

Comment: I was just looking for this too.  I often write long messages in a "contact us" like form, and then hit "submit" only to be shown an error message, and I have lost my composition.
I guess you were in a similar situation.
Maybe a Plugin/ Extension could capture and store textarea data....?

Comment: this extension could be adapted to do it https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/textaid/ppoadiihggafnhokfkpphojggcdigllp?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Of course it isn't stored locally.

Do you really want Firefox to store all of your passwords and credit card numbers?

Comment: No, of course I didn't mean passwords, and I don't have any credit cards :) I meant textarea data.

Comment: @cincplug: POSTs frequently include passwords and credit card numbers.  Saving them locally would be insane.